# Address of array

Tags: arrays, winforms, pointers, c++-cli

while testing my winform app I noticed that, after a fixed time, it crushes and it stop, of course, working. I supposed it could crush because it starts to occupy a lot of memory and, after this time, the system will stop my application and release all the resources occupied. I found that using task manager and monitoring the Physical memory panel. 
In my app I have a lot of managed array and I keep on updating the values of them real time. Maybe, I'm not handling the right way those arrays and slowly but surely they start to occupy all the memory avaible.
My idea was to print somewhere the address of the array and discover if it changes its location. I declared my arrays just like that:

```
array<double, 1>^Array = gcnew array<double, 1>(1000);
```

I know I can find the address of `Array` in this way, in a console application:

```
    array<int, 1>^Array = gcnew array<int,1>(1000);
    for (int i = 0; i<Array->Length; i++) {
        Array[i] = i;
    }

    std::cout << "Address of Array: " << &Array;
    Console::WriteLine();

    Console::ReadLine();
    return 0;
```

It obviously works. 
Now, if I try to find the address of the `array` in a winform application, something goes wrong and I don't know why. For instance, I would have a button that should show up a `MessageBox` or set the text of a `Label` with the address of the array, but I can get only a boolean value ( compiler warning c4305 and compiler warning c4800 ). I tried `interior_ptr` and `pin_ptr` but I didn't have any result.
Does a way exist to know the address of a managed array in a winforms application?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: &Array does not provide you the address of the array at all.  It gives you the address of the local variable that stores a pointer to the array.  &Array[0] would give you the address, you cannot write that for a managed array.  Because its value is meaningless, the garbage collector moves the array object around when it compacts the heap.  Only pinning the array with GCHandle or pin_ptr<> can give you an address.  Be careful, you are getting yourself into trouble with this.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much, your answers are always on point. It seems my problem was caused by the graphics and not by the arrays, so I will avoid this topic but it helped me a lot to learn something new. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Marshal Class.

```
Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(arr, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Lucky me, the problem was not caused by the arrays but it helped me a lot! Thanks again!